# CCRC ClearCase Remote Client - Error 'Config spec for view. . . needs to be synchronized'

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I'm using only CCRC  and I don't have ClearCase locally installed.
I use CCRC Version: 7.1.1   Build id: 7.1.1.03.00_2010C.D100803

I have have a perfectly conventional view on a stream (only I work on this stream).

Initially this view worked fine, I could check in, check out, or hijack as required.

Now, with no apparent change my side, other than ongoing development of code, I get error for every attempted check out, check in , or hijack.  Viz:

***CRVAP0087E CCRC command 'checkout' failed: Config spec for view, "{my view name}", needs to be synchronized with the stream.***

I have tried all three menu options which are available from the 'refresh' menu - namely:

'resource'  ,  'update from repository'  ,  'repair discordance'.

I have tried all three of these menus, starting from the root of my view as it appears in CCRC, on the relevant VOB's and much lower down the source code tree.

'repair discordance' stops with error : ***Error: "com.ibm.rational.clearcase.remote_core.rpc.MalformedResponseException: Premature EOF"***

The other two operations complete normally – but the erroneous situation as regards 'checkout/hijack etc remains.

So how can '***synchronize***' my stream?

My only workaround is to create an increasing number of other views on the same stream (These work, at least initially...). Then I can copy files locally between streams using BeyondCompare.

However, I'm contracting to a very sophisticated user of ClearCase who have have hundreds of work streams in complex trees. I myself am working across multiple streams. It will be easy to disastrously 'copy then deliver' into the wrong stream and wipe out someone else's work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> with no apparent change my side

If anyone has modified the configuration (baselines) of that stream (even though you are the only one to work on it), then the associated views (here your CCRC view) will need to regenerate their config spec in accordance with the new Stream configuration (which is what "synchronize" means.

See the IBM technote "[Synchronize a CCRC view with a shared UCM stream](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21246264&ratlid=cctocbody)": the menu "Update Roesource" is the way to do just that.

[image: Update Resource]

Comment: What version are you using please?  The menu structure in CCRC Version 7.1.1   is quite different.  There is no 'Tools' menu, nor is there an 'update resource', or 'restore menu' available – the only menu option of this type is refresh - and I've already tried all three of the sub menus under refresh.

Comment: @Tony: true, the technote was for CCRC7.0.x. I am using CCRC 7.1.2 and have also the same 'Refresh' submenu. I recommend gathering logs on the CCRC server side, during one of your refresh session: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21413762

Comment: @Tony: If I understand correctly your case (mismatch between local view config and Stream config), this has nothing to do with a discordance (which is explained in detail in this IBM technote: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21305088)

Answer (score 1):

In CCRC 7.1.2, the operation is "Refresh -> Update from Repository".
There also is a tool icon for "Update from Repository".

Answer (score 1):

Please try to remove the load rules and and them back in the "Edit View Configuration" window.
After this, please try use the "Update from Repository" option again. This worked for me.